# Proof that $\int_0^{+\infty} x^2 \cos(e^x)dx$ converges

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

I'm trying to prove that the improper integral
$$
\int_0^{+\infty} x^2 \cos(e^x) dx
$$
converges.

The only solution I see here is integration by parts, but it leads me to the cosine integral, which clearly does not correspond to the difficulty level of the problem. The task obviously has some more elementary simple solution, but I don't see it.

Comment: Question: why is it presumed to converge in the first place? Based on how ill-behaved the integrand is, I'd conjecture it diverges instead.

Comment: @PrincessEev That's what it says in the problem book. Wolfram alpha thinks the same: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5Dcos%5C%2840%29Exp%5Bx%5D%5C%2841%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C%E2%88%9E%7D%5D

Comment: I've seen WolframAlpha and textbooks be wrong before, so I still am somewhat skeptical.

Comment: Okay I stand corrected, I found a solution